# Transform structured data to JSON format using Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've my "Structured data" as shown below, I need to transform it to the below shown "Expected results" type. My "Output schema" is shown as well. Appreciate if you can provide some help on how I can achieve this using Spark Scala code.

Note: Grouping on the structured data to be done the columns `SN` and `VIN`. 
There should be one row for the same `SN` and `VIN`, if either `SN` or `VIN` changes, then data to be present in the next row.

Structured data:

```
+-----------------+-------------+--------------------+---+
|VIN              |ST           |SV                  |SN |
|FU74HZ501740XXXXX|1566799999225|44.0                |APP|
|FU74HZ501740XXXXX|1566800002758|61.0                |APP|
|FU74HZ501740XXXXX|1566800009446|23.39               |ASP|
```

Expected results:

[image]

Output schema:

```
val outputSchema = StructType(
  List(
    StructField("VIN", StringType, true),
    StructField("EVENTS", ArrayType(
        StructType(Array(
          StructField("SN", StringType, true),
          StructField("ST", IntegerType, true),
          StructField("SV", DoubleType, true)
        ))))
  )
)
```

Comment: Please add text instead of images in your question. It makes it easier for us to reproduce the problem based on your current dataset.

Comment: Which column are you grouping by here? `SN`?

Comment: Hello @Shaido, yes, grouping should be done on column SN... i want to loop through the SN column and include SN, ST, SV within the single array of column EVENTS, and VIN as another column as shown in the expected results.

Comment: @AnilKumarKB: What would happen if SN have different valeus for the same VIN? For example, in your example if the VIN in second row is different from the first row.

Comment: Hello @Shaido sorry for the confusion, it should be grouped by SN and VIN. ex: one row for the same SN and VIN. If either SN or VIN changes, then data to be present in the next row.

Comment: @AnilKumarKB: Can you add that to the question? It would be better to replace the images with text as well as indicated by philantrovert as well. I should be able to take some time to write an answer quite soon.

Comment: @Shaido, removed the image and added the data for "Structured Data".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Spark 2.1 you can achieve this using `struct` and `collect_list`.

```
val df_2 = Seq(
  ("FU74HZ501740XXXX",1566799999225.0,44.0,"APP"),
  ("FU74HZ501740XXXX",1566800002758.0,61.0,"APP"),
  ("FU74HZ501740XXXX",1566800009446.0,23.39,"ASP")
).toDF("vin","st","sv","sn") 

df_2.show(false)
+----------------+-----------------+-----+---+
|vin             |st               |sv   |sn |
+----------------+-----------------+-----+---+
|FU74HZ501740XXXX|1.566799999225E12|44.0 |APP|
|FU74HZ501740XXXX|1.566800002758E12|61.0 |APP|
|FU74HZ501740XXXX|1.566800009446E12|23.39|ASP|
+----------------+-----------------+-----+---+
```

Use `collect_list` with `struct`:

```
df_2.groupBy("vin","sn")
  .agg(collect_list(struct($"st", $"sv",$"sn")).as("events"))
  .withColumn("events",to_json($"events"))
  .drop(col("sn"))
```

This will give the wwanted output:

```
+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|vin             |events                                                                                       |
+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|FU74HZ501740XXXX|[{"st":1.566800009446E12,"sv":23.39,"sn":"ASP"}]                                             |
|FU74HZ501740XXXX|[{"st":1.566799999225E12,"sv":44.0,"sn":"APP"},{"st":1.566800002758E12,"sv":61.0,"sn":"APP"}]|
+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: +1. You can have the `to_json` inside the `agg` (`collect_list(to_json(struct(...`) to avoid an extra `withColumn`. This should be possible with older Spark versions as well, probably from version 2.1 when `to_json` was introduced.

Comment: @AnilKumarKB great

Answer (score 1):

You can get it via SparkSession.

```scala
val df = spark.read.json("/path/to/json/file/test.json")
```

here spark is the SparkSession object

Comment: Note that the question is not about reading a json file but transforming a dataframe to have a array column with json elements.

Comment: I understood the structured data that can be transformed into a json, didnt take it as dataframe. My bad.